# React MUI Class name collisions when using a library

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, name-collision

We integrated a library into our Creatives project similar to how is being used in one of our pages.

I noticed that when i interact with a graph
there are lots of empty `<style data-jss>`  tags  are being generated and are overriding the current style of the page.

Those styles are being injected by mui and are overriding initial styles
and breaking the current page design

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this name collusion was found in mui docs
https://v4.mui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator

```
const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName({
  seed: 'ctv-'
});
```

by adding

```
 <ThemeProvider>
      <StylesProvider generateClassName={generateClassName}>
...
</TheamProvider>
```